# Conteúdo comum tabs/pills do bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap

Uso tab/pills do bootstrap e o conteúdo das tabs é quase igual, diferenciando somente alguns campos. Existe uma forma de aproveitar o que há de comum entre eles?

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
     <h3>HOME</h3>
     <p>Campo A</p>
     <p>Campo B</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>MENU 1</h3>
    <p>Campo A</p>
    <p>Campo B</p>
    <p>Campo C</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>MENU 2</h3>
    <p>Campo A</p>
    <p>Campo B</p>
    <p>Campo D</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>MENU 3</h3>
    <p>Campo X</p>
    <p>Campo Y</p>
    <p>Campo Z</p>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Pode partilhar também o código relevante e e dizer ao certo o que quer sff

Comment: Não creio que só com a funcionalidade default de bootstrap consiga isso, tem usar jquery/javascript

Comment: Sem problemas....vc tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Dê-me uns mins, vou fazer com jquery

Comment: tabs e pills? são a mesma estrutura a unica coisa que muda é a classe `nav-pills` para `nav-tabs`

Comment: A unica coisa que podes sistematizar é no servidor, gerar esse HTML de forma organizada. Que linguagem tens no servidor? De resto não vezo que possas "economizar" no HTML uma vez que não é uma linguagem de programação onde possas guardar variáveis ou fazer loops para gerar conteúdo.